# Preview a file on a webpage

Tags: php, javascript

I have many documents on my server that are available for my visitors to download. I have a display set up like so:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="span4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/320X200" alt="ALT NAME">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Header Name</h3> 
        <p>Description</p>
        <p align="center"><a href="assets/documents/NHSHandbook1314.doc" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Download</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now within this I currently have a image as the main display for each document. I am wanting to display a preview of the document in that space. Maybe a screenshot completed by the browser on page load of just the first page of the document.

I have tried `<iframe src="assets/documents/NHSHandbook1314.doc" width="230" height="144"></iframe>` instead of the image but that resulted in nothing being displayed in the iframe and the document downloading as soon as the page loads.

I would like to do this using javascript or php on page load. I basically want the browser to take a "screenshot" of the external document and then display it for the visitor to preview. I don't want them to be able to interact "read" the document from the preview, just see what they are downloading. (at least the first page)

I hope that makes sense on what I am wanting to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers cannot render Microsoft Word documents. You will need to generate some sort of thumbnail on the server and display that.

Comment: Agreed. Once the server has done the processing, it's best to store the result in a database / file system and reference it in your code to prevent the server from processing it on each request. I am not aware of any libraries which will allow you to do the processing, but I'm sure a Google search will help you out on that front.